# How to create SVG asset in Android from HTTP response?

Tags: android

I have a REST endpoint which return am a JSON response. One of the keys holds the image information in the SVG format. How can I parse this information and store this SVG as a vector asset in android drawables. After saving this I want to reuse it to render on my screen for future use.

### Sample code:

```
Call < BarnPlan > getBarnPlan = client.getBarnPlan(token, barnIdList.get(0));
getBarnPlan.enqueue(new Callback < BarnPlan > () {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call < BarnPlan > call,
  @NonNull Response < BarnPlan > response) {
  int responseCode = response.code();

  switch (responseCode) {
   case 200:
    if (response.body() != null) {

    }
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(@NonNull Call < BarnPlan > call,
  @NonNull Throwable t) {

 }
});
```

JSON RESPONSE:

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"success": true,
"statusMessage": "Ok",
"value": "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) --> <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="89.444817mm" height="154.33426mm" viewBox="0 0 89.444817 154.33426" version="1.1" id="svg7936" sodipodi:docname="Büro.svg" inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)"> <defs id="defs2" /> <sodipodi:namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity "
}
```

The Pojo class BarnPlan contains the xml(SVG) response in the form of a string that I want to convert to vector asset.

Comment: the `assets` directory is read-only... so this is not an available option. that's not even `SVG`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, thank you for your reply. The given XML is SVG which is encoded in XML format. I have not given the entire response as the SVG is very lengthy. What do you suggest is the best way to handle these kinds of response? Because I do not want to make a request to again to aquire the SVG resource.

Comment: just look at what you've posted... there is no `SVG`; in best case that's the beginning of one. [AndroidSVG](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) might be the most easy to parse that string... assuming it would be valid `SVG`. even the surrounding `JSON` is invalid, because the double `"` quotes are not being properly escaped.